# Text frame automatically adjusting when scaling text up. Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, cs6

Is there a way to have the text frame adjust while I am scaling up the text?
The text just disappears whenever I increase the size of the text.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are several ways it can be done, or rather ways to work around the problem.  Here are a few off the top of my head.  The following examples use Illustrator CC, but the same should be possible in CS6. I don't have an old copy available to demonstrate.

1. Select the text box with the Selection Tool (V). In the tool options along the top, engage the Constrain Width and Height Proportions (chain link icon), then change the width or height.

[image]

Or

2. Draw a shape next to your text frame. Select both shape and text frame, click and drag a corner handle to rescale the frame and text. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking and dragging if you want to constrain the proportions. Delete the extra shape after you've finished.

[image]

Or

3. If you know there's going to be some text you want to scale. Don't put it in a text frame at all. Click once on the page with the text tool to create a dynamic text box instead. This is a kind of text box which scales as you type.  You can then scale the text and its box by simply changing the font size. Or you can even click and drag the corner handles to scale it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

another option you might be wanting is 'Type' in the toolbar > 'area type options' > Here you see a tick box for auto size. Select this.

When selected, changes you make to text, i.e. if you was to use an extension for xml application for example, it will automatically update, so when additional text is applied the text frame will drop to compensate, otherwise if you don't adjust manually or have this ticked, the frame will cause text to drop off.